# How to prevent "vagrant halt" for production machine?

Tags: deployment, vagrant, production-environment, collaboration

On my team, we're using vagrant for both development (dev) and production (web).

It works great, but sometimes, my team will accidentally run `vagrant halt` to halt their dev server, but this also brings down the production (web) server. **Yikes!**

Is there anyway for me to prevent them from halting the production server? Like disabling the command or password protecting?

Comment: At first glance, I'd write a shell or batch script that wraps vagrant command and change its behaviour in the way you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[vagrant-managed-servers](https://github.com/tknerr/vagrant-managed-servers) plugin might help when using Vagrant with production servers.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following to the top of your `Vagrantfile`:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    if ARGV[0] == 'halt'
      if ARGV[1] != 'dev'
        puts "Sorry! No way I am letting you do that!"
        ARGV.clear
      end
    end
end
```

What this does is it looks at the command line arguments supplied to Vagrant and if you just run `vagrant halt` it will not allow it to happen. If you run `vagrant halt dev` however it would allow the command through and it would halt only the box called `dev`